# Hi. With a React / Redux app on Firefox (newest), I try downloading a file with multiple spaces in the filename, and they become single spaces

Tags: reactjs, go, firefox

I know there are several versions of this question here, but I've tried as many of the
recommendations in them as I can, yet it doesn't seem to work. Most of those suggest
setting the Content-Disposition header item.  From the JS frontend, I've set it using

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=*"Dbase%20%20%20Emails%20-%20Copy.xlsx"; 
    filename="Dbase%20%20%20Emails%20-%20Copy.xlsx"
<or>
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=*UTF-8''Dbase%20%20%20Emails%20-%20Copy.xlsx
<or>
encodeURI("Dbase   Emails - Copy.xlsx")
<or>
filename="Dbase   Emails - Copy.xlsx"
```

Or I've tried setting it on the response header, a golang backend, with pretty much the same form,
but Firefox continues to ignore whatever is passed across in the header, and you see under "File"
in the devtools a decoded:  "Dbase Emails - Copy.xlsx" and in the response header, you see
correctly, this:

```
attachment; filename=*"Dbase%20%20%20Emails%20-%20Copy.xlsx"; 
    filename="Dbase%20%20%20Emails%20-%20Copy.xlsx"
```

That seems right, what can I do to make Firefox download it as the correct name?

Thanks -
Kev

I'd attempted all I could try from previous issues such as:

[How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Answer (score 0):

For the current Firefox (version `111.0.1`), hacking the `Content-Disposition` header does not help at all. Because Firefox will sanitize the filename and compress whitespaces.

I don't know why you want to keep the whitespaces, but please note that the `filename` parameter provides mostly indicative information, and all the browsers would sanitize the filename. For example, Chrome on Linux will replace `/` in the filename with `_`.

BTW, `filename=*UTF-8` should be `filename*=UTF-8`.

References:

1. Firefox source code that calls `DownloadPaths.sanitize`: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/bce007ba1a3fdb155321a15a3430395dddbccb4a/toolkit/mozapps/downloads/HelperAppDlg.jsm#l428

   Note: The source code is not for the current version. But the behavior is the same.
2. Some discussions on compressing whitespaces: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1637973
3. The `Content-Disposition` header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Well, I suppose that's kind of a depressing answer about the behavior. Would want to keep the spaces as that's what a user wants.  Saved the file as "NA   ME", they want it to remain "NA   ME", not become "NA ME".

Comment: A workaround is modify the server code to zip the file so that you can keep the name untouched.